# New York subway Q train - view of Brooklyn Bridge

Tags: public-transport, new-york-city

Does the Q line from Manhattan to Flatbush use the Manhattan Bridge or an East River tunnel?

In the old days when it was the BMT Brighton line the express took the bridge and the local the tunnel. I'll be visiting my old Brooklyn neighborhood with my grandkids and want the view of the Brooklyn Bridge on the way. If the Q doesn't do that what are my alternatives from lower Manhattan to Prospect Park?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [MTA's webage on the Q Service](http://web.mta.info/nyct/service/qline.htm) doesn't answer the question.

The [Wikipedia article on the Q line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q_(New_York_City_Subway_service)), however, says the Q service crosses the East River on tracks which lie on the south side of the Manhattan Bridge. Here's a screenshot from that page:

[image]

Since the two bridges are less than a half-mile apart, you should have a good view.

Comment: Another good source is the official NY City Subway map http://web.mta.info/nyct/maps/subwaymap.pdf - this shows that lines B, D, N, and Q all go via Manhattan Bridge.

Comment: @David We did indeed have a good view last Sunday.

Comment: @EthanBolker Great to hear! Thanks for reporting.

Answer (score 3):

As of July 2019, the (Q) Broadway Express - Brighton Local runs from 96 St - Av on the IND 2nd Av Line down the BMT Broadway Express tracks, across the Manhattan Bridge (south side, facing Brooklyn Bridge), and down the BMT Brighton Beach Line to Coney Island - Stillwell Avenue.

It runs on the Manhattan Bridge at all times, including late nights and weekends. The only times the (Q) runs via the Montague Street Tunnel (B'way/Nassau-4 Av Local tracks) are during reroutes where the bridge is closed.

As mentioned in a prior answer, the [official NYC Subway Map](http://web.mta.info/nyct/maps/subwaymap.pdf) notes that the (Q) runs via the Manhattan Bridge. The tracks on the north side of the Manhattan Bridge are used by the 6 Av Express via Chrystie and are not currently used by the (Q).